# text field in a dialog box on a BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to create an empty dialog box with a text field inside. When the user enters data inside the box he must be redirected to another screen. I want the Dialog box to come up without any statements but must include a textfield

Answer (score 2):

That should be doable with a [PopupScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/PopupScreen.html), [EditField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/EditField.html) and maybe a [ButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html) so the user can let you know he/she is done entering data.

Answer (score 1):

Just create standard OK dialog and then add an EditField to it.

```
BasicEditField inputField = new BasicEditField();                     

Dialog d = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK_CANCEL, "Enter your Username:", Dialog.OK, null, Dialog.DEFAULT_CLOSE);
d.add(inputField);     

int i = d.doModal();

if (i == Dialog.OK) {
    Dialog.inform("Your Username is : " + inputField.getText());
}
```

Here's a complete [tutorial](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/01/bb-java-dialog.html)